# Populating history table (SCD type 4) - stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to build a stored procedure that would deal with history (SCD4) and populate history table based on that.

For example I have tables `Customer` and `Customer_hist` (same columns + `ValidFrom, ValidTo`) that are connected via `IDCust` (`IDCustHist`).

1. Each time new customer is inserted into the `Customer` table (after the procedure is ran), the customer should also be in also in `Customer_hist` table.
2. Each time time customer is changed in `Customer` table (after running procedure), a new record for this customer should appear in `Customer_hist` (and for the old one `ValidTo` should be updated).
3. If there are no changes to record in `Customer` table, nothing should change in `Customer_hist`

Table `Customer`:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Martin |
| 2 | Danny |

Table `CustomerHist`:

| id | name | validFrom | validTo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Martyn | 05:05:2022 | 20:09:2022 |
| 1 | Martin | 21:09:2022 | 31:12:2999 |
| 2 | Danny | 05:05:2022 | 31:12:2999 |

Comment: Hello and welcome, have you considered using a trigger? I think it matches your needs. A trigger for new records and another one for updates. Many use them for creating logs of a table.

Comment: Look at the [temporal table feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16) for SQL Server (2016 and up). It basically does all of this for you, without you having to write tons of code ...

Comment: @Nissus hello and thank you ;) i would prefer using triggers but I'm asked to use SP.